# Covering map on all neighbourhoods is covering map

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}_X), (Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ be topological spaces, and let $f : Y → X$ be a continuous map. Suppose that every $x ∈ X$ is contained in an open neighbourhood $U_x$ which has the property that $f|_{f^{-1}U_x} : f^{-1}U_x → U_x$ is a covering map.

That is, every $U_x$ admits an open covering $\mathcal{U}_x $ such that for all $U ∈ \mathcal{U}_x$, there is a set $\mathcal{W} ⊆ \mathcal{T}_Y$ of pairwise disjoint opens such that $U = \bigsqcup\mathcal{W} = \bigsqcup_{W ∈ \mathcal{W}} W$ and for all $W ∈ \mathcal{W}$,  $f|_W : W \tilde{→} U$ is a homeomorphism.

Consider the set $\mathcal{Z} = \bigcup_{x ∈ X}\mathcal{U}_x$. This is clearly an open covering of $X$. I want this $\mathcal{Z}$ to be an open covering that satisfies the conditions for $f$ to be a covering map of $X$. That is, for every $Z ∈ \mathcal{Z}$, I want to construct a set $\mathcal{V} ⊆ \mathcal{T}_Y$ of pairwise disjoint opens, such that $f^{-1}Z = \bigsqcup \mathcal{V}$ and for all $V ∈ \mathcal{V}$, $f|_V : V \tilde{→} Z$ is a homeomorphism.

Can this set $\mathcal{Z}$ do the job? If so, I am still not sure whether I'm basically there, or have actually not yet seen any key insight to prove this.

Comment: Isn't that kind of obvious? I mean for any $x\in X$ we want an open neighbourhood $V_x$ such that $f^{-1}(V_x)$ is a disjoint union of sets each mapped homeomorphically onto $V_x$. All you need to do is pick such $V_x$ as a subset of $U_x$, which automatically yields the result.

Comment: I will elaborate a bit more. We know, of course, that any $Z ∈ \mathcal{Z}$ is in _some_ $\mathcal{U}_x$, but I feared that we may get into trouble if the corresponding open sets in $\mathcal{W}$ _were_ pairwise disjoint before, but no longer. But I think that's just not the case, because we restricted everything to an element of _one_ $\mathcal{U}_x$. But have we, though? What if our $Z ∈ \mathcal{Z}$ was in $\mathcal{U}_x ∩ \mathcal{U}_y$, for some $x ≠ y$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pairwise disjoint before but no longer". If $f_{|f^{-1}(U_x)}$ is a covering map then for some open subset $V_x\subseteq U_x$ we have that $f_{|f^{-1}(U_x)}^{-1}(V_x)$ is a disjoint union of open subsets such that $f_{|f^{-1}(U_x)}$ maps them homeomorphically onto $V_x$. Since open subset of open subset is open, then the same remains true if I replace $f_{|f^{-1}(U_x)}$ with $f$. Thus $f$ is a covering map.

Comment: Ah yes, I think I get you now: if $\mathcal{V}_x$ is an open covering of $U_x$, then for each $V ∈ \mathcal{V}_x$, there is a set $\mathcal{W}_x ⊆ \mathcal{T}_{f^{-1}U_x}$ of pairwise disjoint sets that are open in $f^{-1}U_x$, and hence open in $X$. Since each $W ∈ \mathcal{W}_x$ is contained in $f^{-1}U_x$, we simply have $(f|_{f^{-1}U_x})|_W = f|_W$, and thus $f|_W = (f|_{f^{-1}U_x})|_W : W \tilde{→} V$ maps homeomorphically to $V$, whilst $f^{-1}V = (f|_{f^{-1}U})^{-1}V = \bigsqcup \mathcal{W}_x$. So $\bigcup\{\mathcal{V}_x \mid x ∈ X\}$ does the job that makes $f$ a covering map.

Comment: Where the equality $(f|_{f^{-1}U_x})^{-1}V = f^{-1}V$ follows from the fact that we already have $V ⊆ f^{-1}U_x$. (And I forgot to mention that of course the set $\mathcal{W}_x$ contains the sets that form the disjoint union that is $(f|_{f^{-1}U_x})^{-1}V$, by virtue of $f|_{f^{-1}U_x}$, and hence, $f|_{f^{-1}V}$, being a covering map.)

Comment: Ah, shoot, "and hence open in $X$" ↦  "and hence open in $Y$", of course. And, in the latter message:
"$V ⊆ f^{-1}U_x$" ↦  "$f^{-1}V ⊆ f^{-1}U_x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach works, but it is too complicated. You have to show that $f$ is surjective and each $x \in X$ has an open neigborhood $V_x$ which is evenly covered by $f$. You know that $f \mid_{f^{-1}(U_x)} : f^{-1}(U_x) \to U_x$ is a covering map for each $x \in X$. Each $f \mid_{f^{-1}(U_x)}$ is surjective, thus $x \in f(Y)$ for all $x$. This means that $f$ is surjective.

Moreover, there exists an open neigborhood $V_x$ of $x$ in  $U_x$ such that $V_x$ is evenly covered by $f \mid_{f^{-1}(U_x)}$. Since $U_x$ is open in $X$, also $V_x$ is open in $X$. Moreover, $(f \mid_{f^{-1}(U_x)})^{-1}(V_x)$ is the disjoint union of open $W_\alpha \subset (f \mid_{f^{-1}(U_x)})^{-1}(V_x)$ which are mapped by $f \mid_{f^{-1}(U_x)}$ homeomorphically onto $V_x$. Hence they are mapped by $f$ itself homeomorphically onto $V_x$. But clearly $f^{-1}(V_x) = (f \mid_{f^{-1}(U_x)})^{-1}(V_x)$, thus $V_x$ is evenly covered by $f$.

Comment: Ah yes, that's more concise. So finally $\bigcup_{x ∈ X} \{V_x\}$ is the open cover of $X$ that does the job, right? (My definition of covering maps begins with: "there exists an open covering of $X$ such that ...".)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Your definition of a covering map is equivalent to that in my answer.